# How to find xpath when we have single inverted comma in our html Ex: ```sortable=" 'name' "```

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

How to find the xpath when we have single inverted comma in our html like this-

```
<td class="ng-binding" sortable="'name'" data-title="'Department Name'" data-title-text="Department Name">dept1</td>
```

I wanted to find the xpath on the basis of class and sortable as mentioned above.

Code which I've tried-

```
//td[@class='ng-binding'][@sortable=''name'']
```

but it's giving me error.

Any valuable assistance.
Please let me know in case of any clarification.

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: you could always use contains, but I would say one of the answers providing the precise value is the correct one. `//<blahblah>[contains(@sortable, 'name')]`

Comment: @Saad Try my answer and get back to me if it works or doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java, should I escape a single quotation mark (') in String (double quoted)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664090/in-java-should-i-escape-a-single-quotation-mark-in-string-double-quoted)

Answer (score 0):

Try `//td[@class='ng-binding'][@sortable="'name'"]`

The problem is that by using 2 consecutive single quotes, it's interpreted as if you are passing in an empty string, and then you got name'' after it before closing the tag, which is just plain invalid.

Or escape like :

```
"//td[@class='ng-binding'][@sortable='\'name\'']"
```

Comment: You xpath works as per my query but when I'm using it in script it shows an error "Invalid character constant"

Comment: Using Shubnam's style, you can also escape the required '. Added to answer.

Comment: Not able to locate path by this.

Comment: Give some information on how you use the XPath, maybe something goes wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Try :-

```
"//td[@name='\'name'\'"
```

OR

```
"//td[@name=\"'name\'"
```

refer :-
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26341/how-to-write-xpath-if-i-have-apostrophe-in-my-xpath-element

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Not able to locate path by this.

Answer (score 0):

This locates the element, now if there are more than "1" that match these conditions, it will fail.  So adding an index "may" be necessary.  Or you need to use different conditions.

```
//td[@class='ng-binding'][contains(@sortable, 'name')][text()='dept1']
```